# How to get list of all available managed properties when using Microsoft Search graph API?

Tags: search, sharepoint-search

Classic SharePoint search API allows getting all available managed properties on an object by passing `managedproperties(filter=600/0/*)` as refiner. (more on [How to find all managed properties of a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/searchguys/how-to-find-all-managed-properties-of-a-document)).

Is there any equivalent trick to discover available properties when using Graph search?

I found nothing similar in [searchRequest resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/searchrequest?view=graph-rest-1.0)